# find the number of the field

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

i have this line in the file:

```
,2,353867835022;11,353681041426390,272023201187741,272-02f-20017-06609,353854100352;11,,,,,,,0854100352,3,00,,O,D,DATA,,,7124395,,,17687,16,HPLMN,M20MSS_TTFILE_8377_20110528170245,M20MSS,W30B22I;0GRI3,1,20110528130013,170054,1,41,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001820,,,,b60a5c0014,1:353867835022::::0854100352::353854100352,,,,,,,,
```

Yes,
this is a comma"," separated file.there is a number 17687 .I want to know what is the number of that field in the line.
i want to use that as a base and include that in a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field #26:

```
% awk -F',' '/17687/ {
    for (f = 0; f < NF; ++f) {
        if ($f == "17687") {
            print $f " found in field number " f " of " NF " on line " NR "."
        }
    }
}' test.csv
17687 found in field number 26 of 75 on line 1.
```

This allows for finding 17687 in multiple fields on multiple lines.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

So, you want the number of commas before the 17687? One way to do it is:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*,)17687,.*$/\1/;s/[^,]//g'|wc -c
```

This grabs everything before the 17687, removes all the non-commas, and counts the number of characters.

Using this in a script, you might do something like:

```
FIELD_NO=`sed -r 's/(^.*,)17687,.*$/\1/;s/[^,]//g'|wc -c`
cut -d',' -f$FIELD_NO some_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tr to change your field separator into a newline, grep to find the line and cat if you wish. For example:

```
$ cat t.csv|tr ',' '\n'|cat -n|grep  17687
    26  17687
```

or better

```
$ cat t.csv|tr ',' '\n'|grep  -n 17687
26:17687
```

Or even

```
$ tr ',' '\n' < t.csv |grep  -n 17687
26:17687
```

Comment: The OP didn't say this, but I would guess that this is the first line of a file with a large number of CSV-style records, so turning the commas into newlines would probably break the ability to tell where a particular record ends.

Answer (score 1):

Perl?

```
FLD="17687"
perl -F/,/ -slane '%h=map{$_,++$i}@F ;print $h{$fld}||0' -- -fld="$FLD"
```

for your example line will print 26 (counted from 1) or "0" if not found. Will search for the last index of string.

or

```
perl -F/,/ -slane 'map{print}grep { $F[$_] eq $fld } 0..$#F;' -- -fld="$FLD"
```

will print all indexes (counted from 0) or nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Small improvement over [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106440/find-the-number-of-the-field/6106542#6106542) version using only one regular expression.

```
sed -r "s/17687,.*|[^,]*//g"  | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk oneliner, single process:

```
awk -F, '/17687/{n=NF;sub(".*,17687,","");print n-NF}' file
```

For large files use the lightning fast `mawk` if available on your platform.